# Sql 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql

I'm having select queries using `order by` and `column alias`.

We are planning to upgrade sql 2000 to 2008.

I think `column alias` are not supported in 2008. I've to write select queries that will work as expected in both sql 2000 and 2008.

Comment: "I think column alias are not supported in 2008" - why do you think so?

Comment: @user1063555: Have you tried running queries that you think will be problematic in SQLServer 2008?

Comment: You are along the correct path, but you didn't ask the question well. See my answer for the behaviour difference I think you mean

Comment: The question is badly worded but there *is* an issue upgrading from SQL Server 2000. Voted to reopen

Answer (score 3):

`order by` and `column alias` are supported in SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: See my answer for why OP is onto something

Answer (score 2):

Ordering by column aliases is supported in SQL 2008. (I just tested this to be absolutely sure that it is true.)

Also, you can repeat the expression used for the column, and the database will recognise that it's the same expression and reuse the result instead of avaluating it again. You can also use column index in the order by, example:

```
order by 1, 4
```

You will rarely experience a query that stops working when updating to a new version. With new versions there are mostly added features. There are a few features that are changed, but you can set the compatibility mode of a database to support features of older versions if neccesary.

Comment: See my answer for why OP is onto something

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases **are** supported in all versions. However, there **is** a difference is how column names and aliases are resolved in the ORDER BY.

See "ORDER BY clause" in ["Behavior Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2005"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Strictly speaking, the ORDER BY clause should operate only on unambiguous column names and aliases available in the SELECT and FROM clauses. SQL Server 2005+ conforms to this, but SQL Server 2000 allows ambiguity. hence the behaviour change

The [SQL Server upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11455) will find this and other issues for you

Comment: You got that backwards. The `order by` clause should *not* operate only on the `select` clause columns. You don't have to include a field in the `select` clause to sort on it.

Comment: @Guffa: true, it was badly worded. Correct now. The behaviour change exists though

Answer (score 0):

Well up to [this Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) Column aliasing is supported in comination with Order by, besides if you need help in any converstion you should show some code  where you are facing problems

Answer (score 0):

Both are supported in 2008. Try to upgrade and if it fails - search for other reasons.